# Updating a NVMe Drive through Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How do I update a NVMe drive to a Standard NVMe Express Controller through Python.
The pictures show how you would do it manually, is there a way to do this all through Python?
Would the pynvme module work?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkxlD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITQW1.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMevo.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the answer is "yes".  In practical terms, the answer is "no".

Anything you can do in Device Manager can be done using the `SetupDi` APIs.  However, those APIs are very wordy and extremely tedious.  They were designed to be used from C, so they have lots of pointers to pointers and system-allocated buffers that are difficult to handle from Python.  There are no convenient wrappers, as far as I am aware, and I've been writing Windows drivers for 30 years.

My advice to you is to give up now.

Comment: Oh ok, is there a way to do it via Command Prompt or PowerShell?

Comment: Maybe, but this is low-level stuff.  There is a tool from the WDK driver kit called "devcon" that exposes a lot of Device Manager.  You can tell it to install a specific driver (by its INF file) onto a specific hardware ID, if you know the hardware ID.

Comment: Would you have a code for this in C or Python by any chance?